# Rust - Casting super trait to trait

Tags: rust, casting, traits

I have a container where I can store items implementing the `CommonBase` trait and I have some other traits (`TypeA` and `TypeB` for example, but there can be unknown number of other `TypeX` traits) with the `CommonBase` as their super trait. I store objects implementing `ItemA` to container and I can get a reference to item back from the container, but as reference to the `CommonBase`.

I want to cast the item back to its original type like this:

```rust
fn cast_to<T: SuperTrait>(val: dyn CommonBase) -> Result<T, dyn Error> {...}
```

Can anyone help please?

Here is my experimental code

```rust
use std::error::Error;
use std::rc::Rc;

pub trait CommonBase {
    fn to_common(self: &Self);
}

pub trait TypeA: CommonBase {
    fn do_a(self: &Self);
}

pub trait TypeB: CommonBase {
    fn do_b(self: &Self);
}

pub struct StructA {}

impl CommonBase for StructA {
    fn to_common(self: &Self) { todo!() }
}

impl TypeA for StructA {
    fn do_a(self: &Self) { todo!() }
}


pub struct StructB {}

impl CommonBase for StructB {
    fn to_common(self: &Self) { todo!() }
}

impl TypeB for StructB {
    fn do_b(self: &Self) { todo!() }
}

pub struct Container {
    items: Vec<Rc<dyn CommonBase>>,
}


impl Container {
    pub fn new() -> Container {
        Container { items: Vec::new() }
    }

    pub fn add(self: &mut Self, item: Rc<dyn CommonBase>) {
        self.items.push(item);
    }

    pub fn get(self, idx: usize) -> Rc<dyn CommonBase> {
        self.items.get(idx).unwrap().clone()
    }
}

fn cast_to<T: CommonBase>(val: Rc<dyn CommonBase>) -> Result<Rc<dyn T>, Box<dyn Error>> {...}  // <- some magic is done here

fn main() {
    let mut container = Container::new();
    let item_a = Rc::new(StructA {});
    let item_b = Rc::new(StructB {});
    container.add(item_a);  // index 0
    container.add(item_b);  // index 1

    let stored_a_as_common: Rc<dyn CommonBase> = container.get_common(0);  // actually TypeA
    let stored_a: Rc<dyn TypeA> = cast_to(stored_a_as_common).unwrap();
    stored_a.do_a();
}
```

Comment: I suggest you take a look at https://ysantos.com/blog/downcast-rust, it gives a few ways you could achieve this

Comment: Rust does not have inheritance, but you can [fake it](https://docs.rs/downcast-rs/1.1.1/downcast_rs/) if you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your code with a few additions.

For this, you need [`std::any::Any`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/trait.Any.html).
Each struct subject to dynamic cast should be known as `dyn Any` in order to try the dynamic cast; this is the purpose of `.as_any()` and `.as_any_mut()` in the example.
Using [`.downcast_ref()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/trait.Any.html#method.downcast_ref) or [`.downcast_mut()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/trait.Any.html#method.downcast_mut) requires you target a **type**, not a trait.

I don't think you can have at the same time two `Rc`s pointing towards the same struct but declared with different `dyn` traits.
The best to do, in my opinion, is to only deal with references (wherever they come from, `Rc` or something else).

You expected an `Error` when the dynamic cast is impossible, then I wrote the function this way.
Note however that `.downcast_ref()` returns an `Option` and this is generally good enough (`None` means that the cast is impossible); we could simplify the code with just this line `val.as_any().downcast_ref::<T>()`.

```rust
use std::error::Error;
use std::rc::Rc;

use std::any::Any;

pub trait CommonBase: Any {
    fn to_common(self: &Self);
    fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any;
    fn as_any_mut(&mut self) -> &mut dyn Any;
}

pub trait TypeA: CommonBase {
    fn do_a(self: &Self);
}

pub trait TypeB: CommonBase {
    fn do_b(self: &Self);
}

pub struct StructA {}

impl CommonBase for StructA {
    fn to_common(self: &Self) {
        todo!()
    }
    fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any {
        self
    }
    fn as_any_mut(&mut self) -> &mut dyn Any {
        self
    }
}

impl TypeA for StructA {
    fn do_a(self: &Self) {
        println!("doing a");
    }
}

pub struct StructB {}

impl CommonBase for StructB {
    fn to_common(self: &Self) {
        todo!()
    }
    fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any {
        self
    }
    fn as_any_mut(&mut self) -> &mut dyn Any {
        self
    }
}

impl TypeB for StructB {
    fn do_b(self: &Self) {
        println!("doing b");
    }
}

pub struct Container {
    items: Vec<Rc<dyn CommonBase>>,
}

impl Container {
    pub fn new() -> Container {
        Container { items: Vec::new() }
    }

    pub fn add(
        self: &mut Self,
        item: Rc<dyn CommonBase>,
    ) {
        self.items.push(item);
    }

    pub fn get(
        &self,
        idx: usize,
    ) -> Rc<dyn CommonBase> {
        self.items.get(idx).unwrap().clone()
    }
}

fn cast_to<T: CommonBase>(
    val: &dyn CommonBase
) -> Result<&T, Box<dyn Error>> {
    if let Some(t_ref) = val.as_any().downcast_ref::<T>() {
        Ok(t_ref)
    } else {
        Err("bad cast")?
    }
}

#[allow(dead_code)] // unused in this example
fn cast_to_mut<T: CommonBase>(
    val: &mut dyn CommonBase
) -> Result<&mut T, Box<dyn Error>> {
    if let Some(t_ref) = val.as_any_mut().downcast_mut::<T>() {
        Ok(t_ref)
    } else {
        Err("bad cast")?
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut container = Container::new();
    let item_a = Rc::new(StructA {});
    let item_b = Rc::new(StructB {});
    container.add(item_a); // index 0
    container.add(item_b); // index 1

    let stored_a_as_common: Rc<dyn CommonBase> = container.get(0); // actually TypeA
    let stored_a: &dyn TypeA =
        cast_to::<StructA>(stored_a_as_common.as_ref()).unwrap();
    stored_a.do_a();

    let stored_b_as_common: Rc<dyn CommonBase> = container.get(1); // actually TypeB
    let stored_b: &dyn TypeB =
        cast_to::<StructB>(stored_b_as_common.as_ref()).unwrap();
    stored_b.do_b();
}
/*
doing a
doing b
*/
```

Comment: Thank you very much. "...requires you target a type, not a trait." - I know Rust has no inheritance (mentioned by @user2407038 but in my head I still think about super traits as super classes. This (quoted) part of your answer explained me a lot about inner machinery of the Rust :-)